# IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.5 Live Template Not Working Instead Uses Emmet

Tags: templates, intellij-idea

I just created a new live template group with a couple templates like:

```
<!--- $VALUE$ Field --->
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('$NAME$', '$VALUE$') !!}
    {!! Form::text('$NAME$', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => $NAME$]) !!}
</div>
```

I defined the template to be used by PHP since this is for a Blade template, but that didn't work, and there was no type for Blade templates (can this even be defined?).  Typing `textfield` I get `<textfield></textfield>` due to Emmet.

How do I get these live templates to work for my custom live templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to choose the defined type to be `HTML` not `PHP`, which I only figured out by selecting `Everywhere` and seeing if it works.  Would be nice to have a way to alias `HTML` as `Blade` etc to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot recreate the issue. The custom template in Blade works fine for me.

Please make sure that you're trying to expand template with the proper shortcut (check `File | Settings | Editor | Live Templates | By default expand with` and `File | Settings | Editor | Live Templates | Options | Expand with`). If everything is correct please file an issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com with additional details: content of blade-file where you're trying to expand template and IDE settings (`File | Export settings`).